# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource even though it is present

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, phonegap

I am building an application with Django + Phonegap. When I try to send an Ajax Request using this function:

```js
<script>
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.0.101/commerce/product/" + localStorage.getItem("toView"),
        type: "GET",
        data: {},

        success: function (json) {

            console.log(json);

        }

        });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I get an error saying in the Chrome console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.101/commerce/product/2.
>   Redirect from 'http://192.168.0.101/commerce/product/2' to
>   'http://192.168.0.101/commerce/product/2/' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.101:3000' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

The problem is in the fact that I am including the requested header. When I open the given URL in chrome and see the server response, I get this.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 16 May 2017 09:42:29 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Content-Length: 89
```

I am also including my server code in `views.py`.

```
def product(request, prod_id):

    #### SOME CODE

    response = JsonResponse(response_data)
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type'

    return response
```

Why am I getting this error? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a slash at the end of url in the `ajax` request:

```
url: "http://192.168.0.101/commerce/product/" + localStorage.getItem("toView") + '/',
```

Django expects a trailing slash to be appended to the URL.

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Why?

Comment: That is the correct url django accepts . And you can see in the error log it complains about the missing slash